# improve cell variables in Matlab

Tags: matlab, variables, optimization, type-conversion

I am preparing training images in Matlab. The problem is the number of images are too much and the size of variables are huge as well. Here is the specification of work:

- There are 10 `.mat` files each contain in average 15000 images. It is in format of 1x15000 **cell** and the size of each file is in average 1.35 GB.(900 kilobytes average per image)
- Average size of each image is 110x110 pixels, each image has different dimensions. Each cell is saved as **single** type with value between 0 and 1.

Loading all 10 `.mat` files at once is impossible because it makes Matlab freezes. My questions are:

1. Isn't the file sizes are too big? 900 kilobytes in average for small 110x110 pixel image is really too much,isn't it?!
2. Is usage of cell of single variable is the best practice for training images? or there exist a more convenient alternative variable type?

update: to compare the image size, [this icon file](http://static9.depositphotos.com/1008244/1074/v/110/depositphotos_10745131-Open-book.jpg) with 110x110 pixel is around 2kb in comparison to 900 kb images in matlab!!!

Comment: Well, loading all 10 files at once would require 13.5GB of RAM, which is generally a lot. Why do you want to load them all at once?

Comment: because I need all the data at once!

Comment: My question is about why data size becomes too large. I am looking for a way to decrease it.

Comment: 120x120 pixel is a size of an icon, an icon with this size is [around 17 kb](https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/favicons/bf01b79523eaf85b25f2ff6446c51aa5f85d00f98336141ca4b28db1.ico?e6da4967ff01baf0192d58743367f3fc). I know this ico file is somehow compressed, but I am sure 900 kb is really too much.

Comment: Why did you choose the datatype `single`?

Comment: @Daniel because each var needs to be a number between 0 and 1 (fuzzy number). Also I see examples that Matlab provides for training data using double: If you run `[xTrainImages, tTrain] = digittrain_dataset;`, you see each cell is a double.

Comment: @Woeitg I cannot see why you must load all images at once, unless you have some amazing data power being able to process all images in a single tic. Otherwise you should  be able to chunk it up to smaller chunks. The code becomes a bit more complicated and execution time a bit longer, but in case you decide you need all data (we cannot say unless we know exactly what you tries to do) I cannot see that you have a choice. Apart from this I also see 900kb as too much. An image of size 110*110 using a bitmap of doubles shouldd take 110*110 *4(3 colors+ transparency)*4 (single)=193,600 bytes.